vba - groups of option buttons - activex - application-defined or object-defined error
I am trying to create a tool for a department where they have to review up to 85 different standards related to submitted documentation. Each standard can have up to 27 points to answer 'met', 'not met' or 'incomplete'. The end goal is to populate the reasons for 'not met' or 'incomplete' in order to advise the applicant.
I need to create numerous groups with three option buttons (activex).  For this one standard (CE2) I am using the following vba code which should populate the 27 groups of 3 option buttons.  I am getting an error message even though I did it exactly as demonstrated in a tutorial.
The error message is run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined
Sub AddOptionCE2()

j = 1

For Each cell In Range("S8:U35")

Set obj = OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.OptionButton.l", Left:=cell.Left + 1 / 3 * cell.Width, Top:=cell.Top * 1.02, Width:=cell.Width / 3, Height:=cell.Height * 0.8)

With obj
.Object.Caption = ""
.LinkedCell = cell.Address
.Object.GroupName = j
n = n + 1
If n = 3 Then
j = j + 1
n = 0
    End If
     End With
cell.Font.Color = vbWhite
cell.Value = False
Next

End Sub


I ran the code and what should have occurred is the groups of three option buttons should populate in columns s-u in rows 8-35.


Qaulify OLEObjects with the Sheet object
classtype:="Forms.OptionButton.l" - The last l should be 1.

Set obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.OptionButton.1", Left:=cell.Left + 1 / 3 * cell.Width, Top:=cell.Top * 1.02, Width:=cell.Width / 3, Height:=cell.Height * 0.8)


Thank you! I figured it would be something simple. Remembering those ';' days.
